How to build sequence in MySQL using ROW_NUMBER while some values of sequence are present?
Hello stack overflow community. I've got a following problem.
Given the following, I have an entries table
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

Which contains the following values:
INSERT INTO `entries` (`name`, `sort_order`) VALUES
('a', NULL),
('c', 2),
('b', 3),
('d', NULL),
('e', NULL),
('f', NULL),
('g', NULL),
('h', NULL),
('i', 5),
('ii', 4);

What is the best possible way to query and sort values by name asc keeping values with defined sort_order in its positions?
I tried different workarounds with ROW_NUMBER() and CTE but nothing worked.
Here's the query, however it returns incorrect results.
WITH ranked_entries AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `name` ASC) AS `rn`
    FROM entries
),
merged_entries AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        COALESCE (`sort_order`, `rn`) AS merged_rank
    FROM ranked_entries
)
SELECT * FROM merged_entries ORDER BY merged_rank ASC;

The expected result should be the following:



name
sort_order




a
1


c
2


b
3


ii
4


I
5


d
6


e
7


f
8


g
9


h
10




I don't understand the logic. Where does sort_order=6 come from for d?

Do you have to do this in SQL? It will probably be easier in a real programming language with arrays.

It should be alphabetical order. d - is next value sorted by alphabetical order. Yes, I need this in MySQL. We have defined positions for c, b, ii and i. The rest should be sorted by name asc.

But it's not alphabetical order because i is before d.

Why is a before b but d is after i?

Yes, "I" has custom defined sort order. So the idea is the following: the rows with defined positions must be on their places. The rest must be returned in alphabetical order.

But what you haven't specified is how those two groups should be ordered between themselves. Why does a go before the rows with defined positions, but d goes after them?

This is required to pin some of the records to the positions which user defines himself. That's why some of the records are not going in alphabetical order.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It looks like you somehow want d to get 6 because 1-5 are already taken. But ROW_NUMBER() won't skip over the defined sort_order values.

I love ❤️ it...

Why not possible ?
So, the logic behind this answer is,

First need to short the names where sort_order is not null - Table T1
Next need to short the names where sort_order is null    - Table T2

Now create an empty table, T0 with length of entries with columns name as empty data and rn as ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL).
And tables are showing as follows:

Now, join Tables T0 & T1 on columns rn, short_order respectively, to get the Table T3 and also create a row_number (name_null_rn) where name is null
Then, join Tables T3 & T2 on columns name_null_rn & rn respectively and merge  T3 & T2 names in that joining.
Your Final Query is:
with T0 AS (
    select '' as name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS `rn`
    from entries
),
T1 as (
    select *
    from entries
    where sort_order is not null
    order by sort_order asc
) -- select * from T1
, T2 as (
    select name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `name` ASC) AS `rn`
    from entries
    where sort_order is null
    order by name asc
) -- select * from T2;
, T3 as (
    SELECT 
        T1.name as name,
        T0.rn,
        case when (T1.name is null)
            then row_number() over (partition by T1.name) 
        end as name_null_rn
    from T0 LEFT JOIN T1
    ON T0.rn = T1.sort_order
) -- select * from T3;
select 
    COALESCE(T3.name, T2.name) as name,
    T3.rn as sort_order
from T3 left join T2
on T3.name_null_rn = T2.rn
order by T3.rn;

Final Output already show in attached image.
Check Sample query line by line: db<>fiddle
Happy Coding !!!!!!

@user3486769
After understanding my logic you can modify SQL query. I could make it complicated. Since this is a complex question, I made it as simple as possible.
Modify the query according to your requirements.

Hi Art,
Thank you so much for your thoughtful, comprehensive answer and for taking the time to help me. It works perfectly! I really appreciate your help.

Welcome @user3486769 ... It's give me a kick to understand the logic
